# Bad quality mesh, Narrow tris as result of Ctrl+t (exporting stl file)

Tags: mesh, export, faces, conversion

I am trying to make a relatively simple 3D-model. resulted quad mesh is very good (fig). however, when I convert the quads to tris I would get this very narrow triangles which I do not want. the only reason that I change the quads to tris is that I need to export the .Stl file, and apparently .stl automatically change the mesh to triangles.

is there any way to avoid this narrow bad quality triangles?

I've tried to merge them with the adjacent faces, but then they are not triangles anymore, and when I import it as stl file the same narrow triform.
 [image]

Comment: And the most important, .stl format structure, no wonder three vertices faces : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)

Comment: Yes, I have already removed double vertices

Comment: could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: I think you should change geometry a bit then. So instead of having Ngons around windows which might not be converted as expected deal with quads only [like in example](http://imgur.com/PiVxuoX). Also does it occur if importing .stl back in Blender ?

Comment: Thanks, how can make sure that I only have quads and no Ngons? Yes it happens when I import it to blender again. but also when I import it to other meshing software I can see the problem.

Comment: thanks, I get your point. I also tried it with faces that I was sure that are quads. however, at corner of the window instead of having two triangles for each quad, I got 3, which one of the was very narrow at the corner.

Comment: "An STL file describes a raw unstructured triangulated surface by the unit normal and vertices (ordered by the right-hand rule) of the triangles using a three-dimensional Cartesian coordinate system."

Answer (score 2):

So here is what I did and it worked for me.

After I got the original mesh (left figure on top), I use **Remesh** modifier with mode set to *Smooth*. This way I got a very high quality mesh with only quads. When I triangulated the high quality quad mesh none of them became narrow.
However, the size of the .stl file becomes very large. Therefore, I use **Decimate** modifier to lower the number of faces and keep checking the mesh quality with 3D printing add-on.